# Python - For loop and threads doesn't want to work together?

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

So iam playing around with threads now and I have come to the stage that the thread indeed works but I think i'm having issue with for loop. So the for loop works only inside the code but whenever I want it to run through entire whole code. Then it will just take the last object in the Json file.

**The code**

```
#Read json File
with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

threads = []
for i in range(len(config)):
    p = threading.Thread(args=(config[i]))
    threads.append(p)
    p.start()
    print()
    print(config[i])


NameUrl = config[i]["Url"]

myNote = config[i]["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config[i]["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config[i]["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config[i]["ZipCode"],
                "given_name": config[i]["Name"],
                "Last_name": config[i]["LastName"],
                "street_address": config[i]["Address"],
                "postal_code": config[i]["ZipCode"],
                "city": config[i]["City"],
                "country": config[i]["Country"],
                "email": config[i]["Email"],
                "phone": config[i]["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config[i]["Color"],
            "house_number": config[i]["houseNumber"],
            "year": config[i]["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

So as you can see the code there is a thread at the beginning but I don't know the issue why it doesnt go through the whole code? maybe any see the issue?

This is the issue

```
    threads = []
for i in range(len(config)):
    p = threading.Thread(args=(config[i]))
    threads.append(p)
    p.start()
    print()
    print(config[i])
```

Comment: And please. If there is anything missing. Feel free to comment and I will post it right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a target to the thread, if not there is no point in using multithreading.

```
#p = threading.Thread(target=function_name, args=(config[i]))
#try something like this
def yourfucntion(config):
     #do your thing
     pass
if __name__ =='__main__':
    with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
          config = json.load(json_data)
    threads=[]
    for i,e in enum(config):
          threads.append(threading.Thread(target=yourfunction,args=(config[i] or e))
```

Comment: Oh. What is my target if I just want to run for beginning if I might ask? Like from the top?.. like in the code I showed?

Comment: Why exactly are you using threading in this code?, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Oh. Basically I have exemple 5-20 json objects. What I want them to do to make them run through a each thread to make the progress faster overall. So that each json object will run through the code with its own info from Json. Pretty much, You understand the concepT?

Comment: You should try doing it inside your __main__ function and build a function for processing json data where you can supply target=function_name , args= config[i] and put it in a for loop to produce multiple threads.

Comment: I quite dont understand the the ```def yourfunction(config)```. Do you mean in that case ```with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)``` ?

Comment: Oh thank you! Okey I think I know whats going on but there is a issue aswell. I know what the process you mean with the code but the issue is sitting on the target. So my script doesn't really go by a special function. We say I have exemple 11 functions and they are just functions to make easier to see what I have coded basically. Isn't there a target that just go by main()? So it goes from the start to the end like it would do if you just start any script (A top-down code)? If you understand my point ish?

Comment: @WeInThis yeah the thing is it will not save you any processing power or increase the efficiency. So, why complicate things and also it's good to put the operations inside a function improves credibility of the code.

Comment: If you have a spare time for chat! Please come and join. I think I might be able to show you more the code I have made (Not a big one, just that it might not have a space to edit it all here!) - But I agree. What I did was that I have made a script and then after that just added stuff things I wanna learn. currently im more learning to use threads at this moment and I thought it was just to put a thread at the beginning and then the code would go with top-down method with all the process? I assume its not working like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155182/discussion-between-weinthis-and-perseus784).